# General solution of a second order linear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$I want to find the general solution of $$\frac{\d^2 u(t)}{\d t^2}-4t\frac{\d u(t)}{\d t}+(4t^2-2) u(t) = 0$$
I know that $u(t) = A\cdot e^{t^2}$ is a solution, but I'm stuck on finding this $A$. Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: should it not be $$\frac{d^2u(t)}{dt^2}+4t\frac{du(t)}{dt}+(4t^2-2)u(t)=0$$?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Edited it!

Comment: If $u$ is a function of one variable, then you should use $\frac{d u}{dt}$ instead of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$.

Comment: The function $u(t) = Ae^{t^2}$ works for any constant $A$ since the ODE is linear. If you want to solve for $A$ you need some initial value for $u$ (there is also another general solution to the ODE which you need to find to characterize all general solutions).

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. So I'll have to find the other general solution. I guess this is possible with variation of constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u''-4t u'+(4t^2-2) u = 0 \tag 1$$
You know a solution $u(t) = A\cdot e^{t^2}$. Then consider that $A$ is no longer a constant, but an unknown function $A(t)$.
$$u(t)=A(t)e^{t^2} \tag 2$$
$$u'=e^{t^2}(A'+2tA)$$
$$u''=e^{t^2}(A''+4tA'+2A+4t^2A)$$
$$e^{t^2}(A''+4tA'+2A+4t^2A)-4t(e^{t^2}(A'+2tA))+(4t^2-2)A e^{t^2}  = 0$$
After simplification the equation is reduced to :
$$e^{t^2}A''=0$$
Thus $A''=0$ which leads to 
$$A=c_1t+c_2$$
Bringing it back into Eq.$(2)$ :
$$u(t)=(c_1t+c_2)e^{t^2}$$